# How can I use my PC as a central location for sharing data?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, backup, desktop-computer, file-sharing

All members in my family regularly take photos from their smartphones which we have to then share with others every now and then.

Our Google Photos storage is entirely full. We don't want to regularly delete a huge chunk of our photos and videos. I also want the images and videos to be shared in original quality.

One thing that came to my mind is a personal website where we can all upload our images and videos and then others will be able to download them. However, that will be against the terms and conditions of most hosting providers.

Is there something that I can set up on my local PC to do this?

The files from all our phones will be uploaded to a directory on the PC and people on the local network should be able to download those files. Here is what I have:

1. A PC that is connected to the same network (through Ethernet Cable) as other mobile devices (through WiFi).
2. XAMPP installed to run localhost if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that is against the terms and conditions of most hosting providers?

Comment: Nextcloud, possibly combined with Nextcloud Photos https://nextcloud.com/ & https://github.com/nextcloud/photos

Comment: PhotoPrism https://www.photoprism.app/

Comment: Piwigo https://piwigo.org/

Comment: Make sure you make backups otherwise you might get stabbed.

Comment: [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.com/) in another self-hosted file-sharing server - [TrueNAS](https://www.truenas.com/truenas-core/) offers all the features you're looking for, including plugins for Nextcloud and OwnCloud or the ability to run either within a jail, VM, or docker image

Comment: You can also buy extra storage on your google account. I advise against hosting it on a computer, because harddisks die so you need extra backups anyway.

Comment: @LPChip, agreed, that backup is needed, but *don't rely just on the cloud*, because these services occasionally have outages, lose data, are hacked, change terms of service or go out of business.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways this can be done, but bandwidth and security concerns exist.

The biggest issue is most ISP or internet providers offer 200 or 300mbps download but a much smaller upload speed approx 30mbps is common.  In this case it will be painfully slow to upload any significant number of pictures.  The only way to solve this issue is to pay to upgrade your internet with both a faster upload speed and download speed.  Depending where you live the cost of this step alone might prevent any further progress.

First you will want a domain name which you will have to pay about $50/year.  From say google domains.

Then you either need a static IP or software which updates your DNS every time your IP address changes.

You will want a SSL cert, so you will want to either use certbot or pay for a better cert.

Then there are the software issues which invite security issues.

From there you could setup a VPN like wineguard to block intruders.  Your security is only as good as the length and complexity of the username and password.

Next up software for sharing you have tons of options here.  Dozens of software exist you can host running apache or nginx.  In addition you could use SMB or windows file sharing,ftp, and more.

You would then need to install VPN software on each phone, and the software you use to upload the files to your computer.

You will need to regularly update the software on your computer, and have additional security software to block intruders.